# How can I get the size of the navigation bar in XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

To get the Action Bar size, I can use `?android:attr/actionBarSize`. Is there something similar for the nav bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is 48dp. Though, there is no attr for the size. The only way seems to be through code like so:

```
private int getNavigationBarHeight(Context context, int orientation) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    int id = resources.getIdentifier(
        orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? "navigation_bar_height" : "navigation_bar_height_landscape", "dimen", "android");
    if (id > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can view it in android-sdk/platforms/android-21/data/res/values/public.xml and find out than there is not public resource declared for nav bar.